Possible engine issue
My car is Benz C400 2015. This issue started showing up recently. When I come to a full stop, at a red light for example, and when I let off the brake pedal and push the gas pedal, before it switches the gear from 1 to 2 and sometimes from 2 to 3, it has a little sudden jerks almost every time I start rolling. Does anyone have an idea what that might be? The engine is good and nothing is wrong with it except for this issue that started like two days ago, is it serious, what might be the issue? Thank you
